# Traversing through a sentence word by word

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

How is it possible to traverse through any given sentence word by word? Is there any in-built functions in java? I have no idea how to begin.

Comment: What are the characteristics of words? They are seperated by blanks..

Comment: I would try Scanner. I would begin by writing a main() to reading in a line of text and break it into words.

Comment: Can you post a sample sentence? How long it is? What all delimiters it is using between words?

Comment: @Hasslam  At a very basic level you are somewhat correct however you must remember there are times where special characters will be used, most commonly, commas, periods, semi-colons, quotation marks, question marks, exclamation marks.  The list goes on.  My point is, even once you split a sentence by spaces there is a lot more to be done before you are left with words.

Comment: Remember also that a single space is not always what splits a word.  In many languages, such as English (although not all languages), a period is followed by two spaces.  Be sure to split on one or more spaces so you remove all the white space, or trim once you split.

Comment: @JonTaylor see my answer for handling your idea

Comment: @rohit see my answer for dealing with your feedback

Comment: @Bohemian yeah I had already up voted your answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this:

```
String sentence = "Your sentence here.";
String[] words = sentence.split("\\s+"); // splits by whitespace
for (String word : words) {
    System.out.println(word);
}
```

Comment: What if words have a `,` in between them?

Comment: OP didn't specify requirements for _words_, also he can start with that and learn to do the rest instead of copying our code. No offense, I am a big fan of your answers here, and give you a lot of +1s ;)

Comment: Well, No offense taken. Really. I just added that, so that you can add it to your answer. Since, a sentence of course can have many delimiters between words. But you are right, that OP has not specified that clearly. Else it is perfectly fine :)

Comment: @jlordo.. And thanks for that appreciation. Really I'm glad that my answers help people out there. :) :D

Comment: -1 splitting on just whitespaces too simplistic. See my answer for the simple, straightforward way to successfully split the vast majority of sentences.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of people are suggesting to split on spaces, but even this very sentence contains commas, etc. You should split on more than just spaces; split on punctuation characters too:

```
String words = sentence.split("([\\s.,;:\"?!,.…(){}[\\]%#/]|(- )|( -))+");
```

This regex splits on all reasonably expected punctuation characters. Note that the in-word hyphen and the apostrophe are *not* "punctuation"; they are part of the word.

This approach, or something similar, will also handle non-English character sentences.

Comment: this is worse than splitting on whitespace (which is only an introductory example), because it splits within words that contain non-ascii letters and looses them. This is especially important when dealing with non-english text.

Comment: @jlordo good point - that was rather Anglo-centric of me. I've edited my answer to accommodate all languages.

Comment: was going to say replace most of it with `\\p{Punct}` but than I saw how you nicely handled the hyphen :)

Comment: @jlordo Regarding the hyphen, I thought of an edge case of `"like these:- blah blah"` where the hyphen is punctuation, but has an adjacent non-space char, so I couldn't simply use `" - "` as the non-match, hence the two separate cases of adjacent spaces either side.

Comment: Instead of trying to list anything that breaks word in pattern, we could do something like "`[^a-zA-Z]+`" (but can only handle English)

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] array = input.split(" ");
```

That way the string is converted into an array separated by spaces (you can change the separator in the split()'s argumen) and then you can loop through the array as you want.

Answer (score 1):

Start with `StringTokenizer` for example or use `String.split(" ")`

Comment: Mention: `StringTokenizer` is considered legacy class and is not recommended now according to its javadoc.

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting the sentence by whitespace character.

```
String sentence = "This is a sentence.";

for(String word: sentence.split("\\s+"){
  System.out.println(word);
}
```

Comment: What if words have a `,` in between them?

Answer (score 1):

```
String s="sfgasdfg  jhsadfkjashfd sajdfhjkasdfh hjskafhasj";
String wordArray[] =s.split("\\s+");
for(String sT :wordArray)
{
System.out.println(st);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the String Split function here http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1167964

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have the sentence stored as a string, you could use the [`String.replaceAll("[./,]"," ")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method to remove the stop words and then use the [`String.split("\\s+")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to obtain the individual words making up the phrase.

Comment: Or we can have all those stop words added to the `Regex` passed in split method. `String.split("[ ,.:]");`

Comment: @RohitJain: Indeed, but punctuation marks are usually removed and not considered as *words*

Comment: @npinti.. No. I mean, you don't need to replace your stop words. You can split on all of them, as split takes a Regex.

Comment: @RohitJain: Now I get what you mean. Yes in that case I agree with you :).

Answer (score 0):

I would Say [StringTokenizer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) might help You.

```
        String str = "This is String , split by StringTokenizer, created by mkyong";
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str);

        System.out.println("---- Split by space ------");
        while (st.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(st.nextElement());
        }

        System.out.println("---- Split by comma ',' ------");
        StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");

        while (st2.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println(st2.nextElement());
        }
```

Also `String.split()` may help You:

```
     String[] result = "this is a test".split("\\s");
     for (int x=0; x<result.length; x++)
         System.out.println(result[x]);
```

OUTPUT:

```
this
 is
 a
 test
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use StringTokenizer class which will divide the string into words.

```
      public static void main(String ae[]){
    String st = "This is Java";
    StringTokenizer str= new StringTokenizer(st);
    while(str.hasMoreTokens()){
        System.out.println(str.nextToken());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(
    "Many words//separated.by-different\tcharacters"
        .split("\\W+")));
//[Many, words, separated, by, different, characters]
```